# Allow user to show / hide sites in the android app Feed

Tags: feature-request, android-app, android-app-feed

I am a registered user in [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) and several other sites, only because I had to ask 1 or 2 questions. In general, I have no interests in these sites, so I don't want to see them on my Feed. Is it possible to hide them somehow?

For now, I want to see only 4 sites (could be meta or non-meta) on my Feed. Notifications are not an issue, because I normally don't get any notifications from those not-interested-in-sites; I rarely participate there.

Comment: +1 There should be a **site selection settings**.